# return a value from an axios call invue js

Tags: vue.js, promise, async-await, axios

For each country in my list of countries i need to make an api call with axios to get the length :

```
<div v-for="country in countries" :key="'loop1' + i.id" class="pays__line" >
  <div>{{ matchCount(i.id) }}</div>
</div>
```

And in my script i have that for now but my method matchCount() doesn't return anything (but the console.log return the length in my console):

```
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    countries: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  methods: {
    matchCount(id) {
      this.$axios
        .get(
          `https://api.com/federation/${id}`
        )
        .then(response => {
          console.log("res axios", response.data.length);
          return response.data.length;
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
     }
   }
  };
</script>
```

How can i return the value each time ?

i also tried this way but again the log is ok but nothing is return in my component :

```
matchCount: async function(id) {
  var pop = await this.$axios.get(
    `https://api.com/${id}`
  );
  console.log(pop.data.length.toString());
  return pop.data.length.toString();
}
```

Comment: store the response in any data value.

Comment: but it overwrite the data on each loop and it gives me the same number everytime

Comment: than push it into an array and use it when you require it